# Breeze: Differences between Entity Framework and NHibernate with many to many

Tags: nhibernate, breeze

Here is the situation:

- WebApi v1
- Breeze 1.4.7
- EF 5.0/NHibernate 3.3.1

What We want: A many to many exposed as a many to one. A client can have multiple countries and a country can have multiple clients. A ClientCountry entity has been created for that purpose.

My mapping looks like this:

Entity Framework:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasKey(p => p.Id).Property(p=>p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().Property(p => p.Abbreviation);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().Property(p => p.ClientSinceDate).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().Property(p => p.ClientUntilDate);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().Property(p => p.Website);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasMany(p => p.Contacts).WithRequired(p => p.Client).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasMany(p => p.ClientCountries).WithRequired(p => p.Client).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().HasKey(p => p.Id).Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().Property(p => p.Username);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().HasRequired(p => p.Client);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasKey(p => p.Id).Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity); 
        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().Property(p => p.ValidFrom);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().Property(p => p.ValidTo);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().Property(p => p.Code);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().Property(p => p.DefaultLabel);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().Property(p => p.Description);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().Property(p => p.DisplayOrder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ClientCountry>().HasKey(p => p.Id).Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity); 
        modelBuilder.Entity<ClientCountry>().Property(p => p.ValidFrom);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ClientCountry>().Property(p => p.ValidTo);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ClientCountry>().HasRequired(p => p.Client);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ClientCountry>().HasRequired(p => p.Country);
```

NHibernate:

```
public class BaseMapping<T> : ClassMapping<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    public BaseMapping()
    {
        this.Lazy(true);
        Id(x => x.Id, map => { map.Generator(Generators.GuidComb); });
    }
}

public class ClientMap : BaseMapping<Client>
{
    public ClientMap()
    {
        this.Property(x => x.Name);
        this.Property(x => x.Abbreviation);
        this.Property(x => x.ClientSinceDate, map => map.NotNullable(true));
        this.Property(x => x.ClientUntilDate);
        this.Property(x => x.City);
        this.Property(x => x.Website);

        this.Bag<Department>(x => x.Departments, colmap =>
        {
            colmap.Key(x => x.Column("ClientId"));
            colmap.Inverse(true);
            colmap.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
        }, map =>
        {
            map.OneToMany();
        });

        this.Bag<ClientCountry>(x => x.ClientCountries, colmap =>
        {
            colmap.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
            colmap.Key(p => p.Column("ClientId"));
            colmap.Inverse(true);
        }, map =>
        { 
            map.OneToMany();
        });

        this.Bag<Contact>(x => x.Contacts, colmap =>
        {
            colmap.Key(x => x.Column("ClientId"));
            colmap.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
        }, map =>
        {
            map.OneToMany();
        });
    }
}

public class CountryMap : BusinessRefEntityMapping<Country>
{
    public CountryMap()
    {
        Bag<ClientCountry>(x => x.ClientCountries, colmap =>
        {
            colmap.Cascade(Cascade.All);
            colmap.Key(p => p.Column("CountryId"));
        }, map =>
        {
            map.OneToMany();
        });
    }
}

public class ClientCountryMap : BaseMapping<ClientCountry>
{
    public ClientCountryMap()
    {
        Property(x => x.ValidFrom);
        Property(x => x.ValidTo);

        Property(x => x.ClientId, map =>
        {
            map.Column("ClientId");
            map.Insert(false);
            map.Update(false);
            map.NotNullable(true);
        });
        Property(x => x.CountryId, map =>
        {
            map.Column("CountryId");
            map.Insert(false);
            map.Update(false);
            map.NotNullable(true);
        });

        ManyToOne<Client>(x => x.Client, map =>
        {
            map.Column("ClientId");
            map.Cascade(Cascade.All);
            map.Insert(true);
            map.Update(true);
            map.NotNullable(true);
        });

        ManyToOne<Country>(x => x.Country, map =>
        {
            map.Column("CountryId");
            map.Cascade(Cascade.All);
            map.Insert(true);
            map.Update(true);
            map.NotNullable(true);
        });
    }
}
```

The js code:

```
 $scope.create = function (index) {

    var c = $scope.clients[index];

    var newClientCountry = breezeService.manager.createEntity('ClientCountry', {
        ValidFrom: Date(2013, 01, 01),
        ValidTo: Date(2015, 01, 01),
        Client: c,
        Country: country,
    });


    breezeService.manager.saveChanges()
    .then(function (data) {
        $log.info('client created');
    })
    .fail(function (dat) {
        $log.error('save client failed:' + data)
    })
}
```

The issue:  With NHibernate, saving a clientcountry results in this error message :"not-null property references a null or transient value CdT.EAI.DAL.ClientCountry.Country". With EF, all works as expected.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since there is no feedback yet, here's what we did to make it (more or less) work:

- First, to be able to save a new ClientCountry(many to many with exposed junction table), we must do this:

  ```
  public class ClientCountryMap : BaseMapping<ClientCountry>
  {
      public ClientCountryMap()
      {
          Property(x => x.ValidFrom);
          Property(x => x.ValidTo);
          Property(x => x.ClientId, map =>
          {
              map.Column("ClientId");
              map.Insert(true);
              map.Update(true);
              map.NotNullable(true);
          });
          Property(x => x.CountryId, map =>
          {
              map.Column("CountryId");
              map.Insert(true);
              map.Update(true);
              map.NotNullable(true);
          });
          ManyToOne<Client>(x => x.Client, map =>
          {
              map.Column("ClientId");
              map.Cascade(Cascade.All);
              map.Insert(false);
              map.Update(false);
              map.NotNullable(true);
          });
          ManyToOne<Country>(x => x.Country, map =>
          {
              map.Column("CountryId");
              map.Cascade(Cascade.All);
              map.Insert(false);
              map.Update(false);
              map.NotNullable(true);
          });
      }
  }
  ```

  The difference here is that the insert/update are inverted. `Insert(true)` and `Update(true)` must be set on the foreign key mapping and not the association. It differs from the [breeze doc](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/nhibernate-support) on that point.
- The second is that `Inverse(true)` must be set on each collection association or all your collections will be deleted when updating the parent entity.

With that,changes, it seems to work as expected.

**ps: It is fixed in the latest version (>1.4.8). The comments above don't apply anymore.**