# Breeze - Null or transient value when deleting entity with nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, breeze

Previously I had a bug with the `fixrelationships` function([Breeze: Differences between Entity Framework and NHibernate with many to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684118/breeze-differences-between-entity-framework-and-nhibernate-with-many-to-many/20738514#20738514)) that has been fixed.
Now I face another problem linked to the fix.
I have an entity Request with a many to many relationship called RequestContact. The many to many is exposed as a many to one on both Request and Contact entities. If I delete a RequestContact from a Request, I got a "null or transient value" error in NHibernate.
What's happening:  breeze send my deleted entity over the wire. Once on the server, the relationships of the entity are not loaded (see [code](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Breeze.WebApi.NH/NHRelationshipFixer.cs) line 290) and the delete method crashes since the associations are empty.
The code is similar to my previous post if you want a sample.
Is it a bug? Why associations are not loaded when `EntityState` is `Deleted`?

I made a fix in this [pull request](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/pull/33).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug, but the fix in the pull request causes errors with one-to-one associations in my tests.  It needs some more work.

Comment: Fixed now (in the GitHub source only).  The change is almost the same as what you proposed.  Thanks for your help.